# How to add noise to an image loaded from .mat file?

Tags: matlab

So I have loaded the .mat file:

```
load Yale_32x32.mat;
X = fea';
```

I then can view the image using:

```
imshow(reshape(X(:,1),32,32),[])
```

There are 165 images, so the second dimension can be any number in the range from 1 to 165.  Suppose, I want to add 'salt-pepper' noise to one of the images. If I try to do:

```
J = imnoise(reshape(X(:,1),32,32),'salt & pepper', 0.05);
```

and then:

```
imshow(J,[]);
```

... it will display to me a noise on the purely white background. What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

`X(:,1)` gives me:

```
70
68
49
53
50
50
37
33
26
13
17
61
69
```

109
    ....

etc.

After applying `J = imnoise(X(:,1),'salt & pepper', 0.05);`, I get:

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1

etc.
```

## EDIT

Fixed: I had to normalize my image. Thank you.

Comment: What is `C`? Do you mean `X`?

Comment: What's the reshape thing for? Just imread() and imnoise() work fine.

Comment: Yes, my apologies; indeed, I meant X. Fixed.

Comment: imread() does not work, couldn't you please be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Have you tried your code with any general images like `peppers.png` among the demo built-in ones? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54439-list-of-builtin-demo-images